# exclude xml files from classpath ant

Tags: xml, ant

I want to exclude xml files from classpath.

I have tried :

```
<fileset dir="${dirpath}" excludes="**/*.xml" />
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
<fileset dir="${dirpath}">
    <exclude name="**/*.xml" />
</fileset>
```

Comment: That is the correct syntax. Perhaps there is something else in your Ant build file that is causing unexpected behaviour.